# How to implement ContextMenu on

Tags: android, fastadapter

I am using [mikepenz/FastAdapter](https://github.com/mikepenz/FastAdapter) and 1 want to use context menu.

I am trying to find override method like  `onCreateContextMenu`, but I can't find it. Can anyone show me how to implement it?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is there any code, that is working or even not working? Be sure to follow on [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a question and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: i already follow example from  http://blog.iamsuleiman.com/recyclerview-adapter-android-made-fast-easy/, but instead of having a context menu, i have a action bar menu. i don't know how to change it. can you show me how to do it? thanks

Comment: Can you please be a bit more specific? You want a contextMenu on an item?